# Python - Django - TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on a django application and I'm stuck with these error :

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found
```

Here is my code :

```
class eleve(models.Model):
    ideleve = models.IntegerField(db_column='idEleve',primary_key=True)   
    cp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ville = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    pays = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    annee = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    specialite = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.ideleve)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'statistique_eleve'
```

Traceback :

```
>>> eleve.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/eisti/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 229, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "/home/eisti/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 590, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found
```

Comment: For what do you use `ideleve`? Django handles setting up PKs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why are you trying to cast the **str** representation of you model to `unicode` here:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.ideleve)
```

It should be (if python 3):

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%d' % self.ideleve
```

Or python 2:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%d' % self.ideleve
```